# How can the output of ldd be checked to see of they exist on a different system or not?

Tags: libraries, dependencies, testing

Running ldd on an executable gives the output displayed below.

How can the output be parsed for the library names in the first column and their existence tested on another computer, giving output similar to ldd's output shown below, eg via a remote SSH command, or with the output copied to the target computer and tested there?

> ```
>     linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7728000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76f9000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb76f4000)
>     libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xb75bf000)
>     libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xb759e000)
>     libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb7136000)
>     libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb7087000)
>     libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb7038000)
> ```

In a more general manner given a list with some filenames which are in a given column or can be extracted via a regular expression how can their existence be checked for and the output formatted as list with their paths if they exist or some other text stating if they don't exist?

Comment: (Warning, kludgy): copy the binary over to the target machine and try `ldd $binary | fgrep -i "not found"`? That's fairly OS-agnostic as you haven't specified what distribution it's for. It'll check for **non**-existence, though.

Comment: I asked the question a few months ago and forgot about it http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101824/is-there-a-way-to-determine-what-packages-or-libraries-should-be-loaded-to-suppo. Should I delete it or mark it as duplicate? I don't know if I have the rights for the latter option.

Comment: I want to reopen this question because in this case I want to test if they are actually present on the computer. The other question is on finding which packages contain them

Comment: Sure. Nominated it. I may have an answer to it, too. I'll be sure to link to the sort-of-duplicate one.

Comment: @vfclists You're going to want to edit this one to make it clearer how its a different question.

Comment: Agreed. I can see the difference, but only after reading both questions a few times.

Comment: I have changed the question and also expressed the general case which is more like testing a list for existing files with output indicating their location if they exist or not.